# Import SharePoint 2010 Workflow in to Visual Studio: How to see the code behind?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have imported a Workflow (SharePoint 2010) into VS2010. I found the activities are all locked (with a yellow padlock on the top left corner). How do I unlock them or how do I view the code behind?

Thank you in advance!

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the workflow was made with SharePoint designer, you can't. Sad but true.

Comment: My godness I can't believe it. Thanks Machinegon.